# base64 string from ajax response to img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF service which returns a base64 string equivalent of a bitmap image.

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(ImgBytes);
```

I am using ajax to invoke this service. The code is something like.,

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url: MY_SERVICE_URL,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "html",
     success: AjaxSucceeded,
     error: AjaxFailed
});

function AjaxSucceeded(result, textStatus, request) {
    var binary = "";
    var responseText = request.responseText;
    var responseTextLen = responseText.length;

    for (i = 0; i < responseTextLen; i++) {
         binary += String.fromCharCode(responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 255);
    }

    $("#myimage").attr("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + btoa(binary));
}
```

But i am not able to see any image.

Also i have tried using dataType as "text".

I have tried printing the data I am assigning to the src of the img tag. And i used that data [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bYGum/), where i am able to see the image.

Also i am able to view the image if i hard code the response value like.,

```
document.getElementById("myimage").src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + "Qk02EA4AAA...."
```

I have tried searching various forums. But unfortunately I am not able to figure this out. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is happening in `AjaxSucceeded`. And are you sure you are getting data from `MY_SERVICE_URL`?

Comment: @VDWWD: yes.. i am very sure about it. i am able to log the response value and use the same in "http://jsfiddle.net/bYGum/"

Comment: Show the complete `AjaxSucceeded` function.

Comment: please find the updated query with AjaxSucceeded

Comment: It appears as if you are taking a base64 string and converting its byte values into base64, which would not be useful. Have you tried `$("#myimage").attr("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + response.text);` ?

Comment: I just did that @Traktor53. It throws net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: It works for setting the `src` of an image element using "GetCurrentFrameResult" text copied from your log at "dropbox.com/s/3gmcr2lx22pdjaj/responseLog.txt?dl=0", a US flag eagle on black background.  Does the jquery code work using a valid data URL?

Comment: of course it does. you don't want to convert base64 to base64 twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, you should use like this

```
$("#myimage").attr("src","data:image/jpg;base64," + "Qk02EA4AAA....")
```

Comment: that works only if i use "data:image/jpg;base64," + "Qk02EA4AAA...." .  But it fails if i use "data:image/jpg;base64," + btoa(binary) as in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908019/display-image-in-src-tag-with-response-text-not-base64"

Comment: Can I see the full wcf response?

Comment: please find the log in "https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gmcr2lx22pdjaj/responseLog.txt?dl=0"

Comment: try to use dataType:"json" in ajax and the success method use data.GetCurrentFrameResult

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this much shorter snippet.

```
$.get(MY_SERVICE_URL, function (base64string) {
    $("#myimage").attr("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64string);
});
```

Assuming `MY_SERVICE_URL` only sends the exact result from `return Convert.ToBase64String(ImgBytes);` > `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBD....`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the support. I was able to get through it.

This is what I did .,

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url: MY_SERVICE_URL,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: AjaxSucceeded,
     error: AjaxFailed
});

function AjaxSucceeded(response) {
    $("#myimage").attr("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + Response.GetCurrentFrameResult);
}
```